# How to source environment variables from a script on a remote host when using remote mode in clion?

Tags: clion, remote-server

At my company we use a number of linux servers dedicated to compilation of our codebase. I would like to use CLion's remote working capabilities, but so far I am unable to find a way for CLion to source my ~/.bashrc file, which sources other files that set the env and toolchain.

Is there a way to make clion source a file, .bashrc to be specific, after making the ssh connection to the remote server?

Comment: Have you tried building a command which exports the lines from your bashrc in the ssh command and then gives you a bash prompt? Something like - `ssh <login> -c '${myexports}; bash '`. Once you are in the remote server you are there.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted by CLion's GUI - it only accepts the hostname and port as parameters for the ssh connection, there is no way to inject any arguments into CLions internal invoacation of ssh. I need it to log into a shell that has ~/.bashrc sourced, otherwise the toolchain will not be detected and I won't be able to manually set up every include path, find the right compiler, linker, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of 13.11.2020 there is no way to source a script from the remote machine while working in CLion remotely via ssh.

There is a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8414) for this functionality to be added so if you are reading this in the future, check the web, maybe the situation has changed.

Answer (score 3):

I did find a workaround:

I created a bash script that looks like this:

```
export PATH=/home/user/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH
/home/user/Documents/cmake-3.19.0-rc3-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake $@
```

And set my toolchain's cmake to that file. Now whenever there is a configuration or building operation the script would pick up the arguments, setup the environment and then call cmake with passed parameters.

Comment: It is a neat trick that can be used to also set some variables prior co cmake invocation, but it doesn't quite solve my problem - I am still unable to create a remote connection to a compilation server, work on local sources (with indexed symbols) and compile on the server.

Comment: CLion automatically copies your source files, configure and build then, and then copy the output back to your source machine. Isn't that happening on your setup?